# How to prevent plugin, theme installation failures on Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, customization, themes

I didn't know this site exists. So, I asked it on [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/how-to-prevent-plugin-theme-installation-failures-on-wordpress)

I didn't get a solution still. :-(

---

I am unable to install any theme/plugin to my WordPress 3.0

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.2.3.1.zip…    
Unpacking the package…    
Installing the plugin…    
Could not copy file. /public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/languages/wpcf7-lt_LT.po    
Plugin install failed.

Downloading install package from http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/download/piano-black.2.2.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Could not create directory. /public_html

Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.2.3.1.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Could not create directory. /public_html/blog/wp-content/upgrade/contact-form-7.tmp/contact-form-7
```

I get similar messages everytime. Is there any solution?

Comment: Please copy your full question from over there to here so people reading this page don't have to click over. You can still reference WebApps.

Comment: You need to provide more information here, otherwise this question can not be answered. This needs to be drilled down.

Comment: Please provide more information and feedback otherwise it's not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either the configuration of the path where WordPress is installed (you don't have the right path setup) or if the path is correct, you don't have got enough permissions to modify the file system.

So as this answer is very broad, that's because it is of a very technical nature that is bound  to your concrete hosting environment. Please contact your hosting support and figure out together with them which path and permission settings are needed for your WordPress installation.

In case you copied over your blog from another system, please reset the path related configuration constants and options. Check your `wp-config.php` if you make any specific settings in there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a server configuration issue.  If it's not a path issue on your site (I agree [with hakre](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/558/how-to-prevent-plugin-theme-installation-failures-on-wordpress/563#563), this is my first guess) then it could be a CHMOD problem with your folder and file permissions.  If the server running WordPress doesn't have permission to modify or edit your `wp-content/plugins` folder, you will get multiple "unable to create file" errors every time.